# could have (epistemic modal)

Tags: modal-verbs

I saw the following sentence in this article. [Hong Kong politician hired taxi to fetch TOILET PAPER | Daily Mail Online](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4149228/Hong-Kong-politician-hired-taxi-fetch-TOILET-PAPER.html)

> Many have questioned why she ***couldn't have gone*** to a local
>   convenience store instead of travelling to her former home in the
>   exclusive Peak district.

I am confused about the usage of ***couldn't have gone***. I learnt from this  [thread](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79955/she-couldnt-come-vs-she-couldnt-have-come) that **could** could be an epistemic modal, which refers to possibility. But I do not think the author is saying ***it was impossible for her to have gone to a local convenience store at that night***. So, how should I interpret ***couldn't have gone*** here?

Comment: If I use **didn't go** instead of **couldn't have gone**, what is the nuance of meaning between the two?

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree that this is epistemic.

The question asked of her could have been

> Why didn't you go ... ?

which would be neutral. But a stronger question that might be asked of her is

> Why couldn't you go to a local convenience store ?

with an implication something like "Of all the choices open to you, why was it not possible for you to do this one?" It has a connotation of annoyance or frustration. And it is certainly idiomatic.

"Many questioned why she couldn't have gone" reads to me like the indirect version of that second question. So I think it is the ordinary deontic "Why was it not possible?"

Comment: +1. But I don't think I'd call this 'deontic', since there's no sense of obligation. Some writers call this and futurive *will* 'dynamic' modality, which as near as I can tell means it's not semantically "modal" at all.

Comment: I hadn't come across that term, @StoneyB. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Context decides this.

*She couldn't have gone* can be synonymous with *she was unable to go*.  If the conversation is talking about her ability to do things, this meaning is likely intended.

*She couldn't have gone* can also be synonymous with *it was not possible for her to go* with an express or context-implied *because of X*.  If the conversation is not talking about her, but rather trying to reconstruct a timeline of events, this meaning is likely intended.

Your example doesn't really provide a lot of context by itself, but the source article you've cited fills in the blanks.  This sentence from the source article is the clue:

> After she revealed her story to reporters over the weekend, Lam has been ridiculed on social media.

So your example is talking about her story, therefore is trying to reconstruct a timeline of events, and we are discussing logical conclusions.